# How to filter outgoing traffic?

Tags: insider-threats

There are a lot of programs that check incoming traffic for viruses and other malicious software.

This is yesterday.

Nowadays security means to prevent insider to send information OUT.

Are there any programs that listen to all outgoing traffic and analyse whether it is valuable (containing passwords, keystrokes, voice recorded, geolocation trackings etc) or not?

Comment: The search term you are looking for is "DLP" and "Data Loss Protection" - there is a large and healthy industry of tools for exactly this. Lots of email server software also have filters for particular patterns of data (credit card numbers, etc.)

Comment: That's yesterday too, It has been around for about a decade if not more. Zonealarm did that (preventing programs to communicate with the outside world) on windows years ago. Hey, I've checked Zonealarm and they are still up and running (I thought they might have disappeared), but haven't used their software for years.

Comment: Netflow is now able to inspect layer 7 traffic though it isn't a program like what you've asked for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're aiming for with your question but filtering outgoing traffic through computer software suffers from the same deficiencies like virus scanners and the like. You need a pattern matching software that is able to distinguish what is good and what is bad. If malware records keystrokes, passwords, whatever, it is sufficient to encrypt it and every filter will let it pass because the risk to break business processes by stopping legitimate traffic is too big.
So there is no "yesterday" and "today", all this stuff can be easily tricked with average knowledge available for free on the internet.